# Implement links on single-page web design

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

Simply put: I have a single-page website, for instance www.example.com. How do I make a link pointing to www.example.com/sub not trigger an unload, **but still change the address bar** as if it did?

[example1](http://www.iuvo.si/play)

[example2](http://soulwire.co.uk/hello)

Comment: You're looking for (modern browsers) window `popstate` and `pushstate` AKA **History API**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) can do this.

```
history.pushState({data: "foo"}, "SubPage", "http://www.example.com/sub")
```

You can kind-of use [History JS](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to shim it in for the older browsers (it will fake it with hash links in non-compliant browsers).